# ios - stop in specific angle in a wheel

Tags: ios, rotation

I am working on iOS application, there is a requirement that I have to make a wheel, with this wheel, app will get wheel image from server, then user is able to tap a button to rotate it. 
Input is wheel image and specific angle, I have to stop wheel at that angle! 
Beside of that, the wheel should have velocity while rotating.
In case you have any ideas or solution, please share to me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly do you have problems with?

Comment: Please add your code to the question, and describe exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I think help this link => https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jswheelview

Answer (score 0):

To create this view it is simplest to have a square `UIView` which clips subviews (is a property on `UIView`) and has a corner radius (property on a layer `view.layer.cornerRadius`) set to half the view width (or height). On this view add an image view with the image provided.

To rotate the view you can simply use transform like `view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angleInRadians)`. This property is animatable so you can use `UIView.animate...` methods to animate the rotation. For this case all you need to do is is set the transform inside the animation block to the target angle and view will rotate correctly and will animate. You may also add some options for instance the curve could be ease-in-out which will make wheel start slowly, then accelerate, then slow down and stop.

If your case is that your wheel may make a few circles before stopping at a certain angle then the `UIView` animations may be a bit inappropriate. In that case I would create a repeating timer with interval of `1.0/60.0` so it will trigger 60FPS. When your wheel starts you would save a start date:

```
startDate = Date()
```

and end date:

```
endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(expectedDuration)
```

You also need to save the start angle:

```
startAngle = currentAngle
```

and end angle like:

```
endAngle = CGFloat(Int(currentAngle/(CGFloat.pi*2))*(CGFloat.pi*2)) + // This will roughly return how many circles have currently pass
           CGFloat.pi*(numberOfFullCircles*2) +  // Add full circles
           angleToStopAtInRadians // Add the destination angle
```

Now whenever the timer triggers you need to update the transform of the view to the target rotation. You need to find where in the animation you currently are depending on the current time:

```
let absoluteScale = endDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())/endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
let scale = CGFloat(max(0.0, min(absoluteScale, 1.0)))
```

Then we need to use linear interpolation:

```
currentAngle = startAngle + (endAngle-startAngle)*scale // Use this in the rotation matrix
```

To use non linear (ease out for instance) it is best to modify the scale. For ease out you may for instance use `scale = pow(scale, 1.0/1.3)`. You may play around with these values as you wish or find/create some more interesting algorithms.

Then the last thing that you need is to stop the timer when the animation has ended which is already written in `absoluteScale`: `if absoluteScale >= 1.0` then the animation is complete and you should invalidate the timer and trigger whatever needs to execute after it.

Have fun with this and when you find yourself in trouble please post a new question with some details and code.